# Certificate Store Access denied

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm receiving a System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException Access is denied. when trying to create media service task or job. The app is running on an azure website instance. Everything works locally. Look like the app is unable to write to the certificate store. I have tried elevating the trust level for the app to full with no effect.

```
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Open(OpenFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.EncryptionUtils.SaveCertificateToStore(X509Certificate2 certToStore)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.BaseContentKeyCollection.GetCertificateForProtectionKeyId(DataServiceContext dataContext, String protectionKeyId)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.BaseContentKeyCollection.GetCertificateToEncryptContentKey(DataServiceContext dataContext, ContentKeyType contentKeyType)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.JobData.ProtectTaskConfiguration(TaskData taskData, X509Certificate2& certToUse)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.JobData.Submit()
   at MediaServices.Encoding.Encode_video_h264(IAsset asset)
   at Business.Background_tasks.Kickoff_encoding(IAsset asset, Guid id)
   at Routing.Controllers.BlobsController.UploadBlock(Int32 id)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**Edit**
I have moved the application to a VM and still receive the same exception

**Edit**
Final solution found here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/67216e79-c259-4685-95d0-3a09bab5c0c5/

When running on IIS7 - you can specify to load the user profile of the App Pool. This gives you access to the per user store of the app pool account.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you would expect from Windows Azure Web Sites. You're running in a shared environment together with other Web Sites and for security reasons there are a many things you cannot do.

If you want full control of the machine where your web application is hosted (like full access to the certificate store, making changes in the registry, ...) you should deploy your application to a Web Role.

Comment: Would it still not allow if I moved to WAWS reserved mode?

Comment: I have my doubts. Imagine you have a reserved instance on which you run Web Sites for different customers. You wouldn't want customer A to write certificates to the certificate store and have customer B read these certificates. I didn't test this yet, but I would find it logical that the hosting model is the same when deployed free/shared and reserved.